# To select only one checkbox at a time and execute a particular task on a particular checkbox being selected or both of the checkboxes being unchecked

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I have two checkboxes and the objective is to only allow one checkbox to be selected at a time 
Further different task needs to be executed depending on either selection of a particular checkbox or in case both of the checkboxes are unchecked.
I have implemented this and facing issue in executing the task when one of the checkboxes are checked or both are unchecked

```
<div *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk.checked" 
(click)="uncheckOther(chk)"> {{chk.value}}
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
  checkboxes = [{ checked: false, value: 'Request' }, { checked: false, 
  value: 'Reservation' }];    

  uncheckOther(chk) {
   //uncheck all
   this.checkboxes.forEach(x => {
   if(x.checked == true)
   x.checked = false;
  })

  //check the selected
   if(chk.checked == true) {
   chk.checked = false; 
    } else {
   chk.checked = true;
   }
//Execute task if any one of the checkboxes are selected
   if(chk.value === "Request" && chk.checked == true){
    console.log("call request data")
   } else if(chk.value === "Reservation" && chk.checked == true){
    console.log("call Reservation data");
   }
//Execute task if none of them is checked
   this.checkboxes.forEach(x => {
   if(x.checked === false)
   console.log("call both combined data")
   })
   }
```

Only one checkbox should be selected at a time and some tasks needs to be executed depending on the selected checkbox or both of the checkboxes being unchecked which is also the default case(or might be unchecked by the user)

Comment: Need more explanation

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: So by default when page loads the checkboxes will be unchecked and we will have combined data (Request + Reservation), when user clicks on Request (Checkbox) the Request data will be available , 2nd case User clicks on Reservation(Checkbox) Reservation data will be available, 3rd case now anyone of the checkboxes are checked eg: Request(Checkbox) and user unchecks Request(Checkbox) then again both combined data should be available.

Comment: So I am facing issue in getting the correct checkbox related data(the execute task comment code). Either one of them being checked or both being unchecked

Comment: No that's what I have written only one checkbox should be allowed to be selected that is working , but the execute task thing is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191662/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-enthu).

Comment: 2 objectives = 1. To allow only one checkbox to be checked(Working) . 2. Execute task depending on checkbox selection(Not working)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, hi in a diff scenario , like to trigger an api call depending on which ever checkbox is selected , how that approach can be taken, either one of them or both or none, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need few changes:

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="chk.checked" (ngModelChange)="uncheckOther(chk,$event)"> 
  {{chk.value}}
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
uncheckOther(chk, event) {

  if (event) {
    //uncheck all
    this.checkboxes.forEach(x => {
      if (x.checked == true)
        x.checked = false;
    })
    //check the selected
    if (chk.checked == true) {
      chk.checked = false;
    } else {
      chk.checked = true;
    }
    if (chk.value == "Request") {
      console.log('Call Request API')
    }
    else if (chk.value == "Reservation") {
      console.log('Call Reservation API')
    }
  }
  else {
    console.log('Call Both API')
  }
}
```

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbbpcb)